# Why is the second lowest cost silver plan (SLCSP) premium reported as $0 when no advance premium tax credit (APTC) was taken?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, health-insurance, tax-credit

In the [instructions](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i8962#idm140230413125040) for Form 8962 (Premium Tax Credit), it says:

> If no APTC was paid for your coverage, Form 1095-A, Part III, column B, may be wrong or blank or may report your applicable SLCSP premium as -0-.

My form has it reported as 0. Healthcare.gov provides a [tool](https://www.healthcare.gov/tax-tool/#/premium-tax-credit) to lookup your SLCSP in that case. Why is this necessary? I can't come up with a reason why the column would be wrong. Do they just put 0 as a minor barrier to somebody incorrectly claiming the premium tax credit?